vba extract data from multiple excel files into combined sheet
I have edited my question and added more details.I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out.
edited question : I have multiple Excel files with thousands of rows and several columns containing users login/logout details.I need to find out total time the users have been using the system for each month. I tried to find out user's total time spent based on login/logout pairs details but may be because login/logout timestamp value (for example : 2023/04/15 9:45:30)in same cell.so my code outputs nothing except headers. And also some users have two login values at same time so i tried to use first timestamp value for login but macro does not shows outputs. Any suggestions to make my code more efficient will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance! here is my code :
Sub ExtractDataFromMultipleFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, destlastRow As Long
    Dim loginTimestamp As Date, logoutTimestamp As Date
    Dim totalTime As Double, totalPerUser As Double, totalPerMonth As Double
    Dim loginID As String, currentMonth As String, UserName As String, prevAction As String
    Dim dataArr(1 To 1, 1 To 4) As Variant

    ' Set the folder path where Excel files are located
    folderPath = "/Users/kabu/Desktop"      ' i have not added the actual folder path
    
    'Loop through each file in the folder
    sourceFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While sourceFile <> ""
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & sourceFile)
    Set srcSheet = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Define constants
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = destWs.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    ' Set destination worksheets
    Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESULT")

     ' Add headers to the destination sheet
    destWs.Range("A1").Value = "DATE"
    destWs.Range("B1").Value = "LoginID"
    destWs.Range("C1").Value = "Name"
    destWs.Range("D1").Value = "TotalTime(per user)"
    
    ' Clear existing data in the destination sheet
    destWs.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = srcSheet.Cells(srcSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If srcSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Get" Or srcSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Login" Then
            ' Store login timestamp
            If prevAction = "Get" Or prevAction = "Login" Then
                ' Use the earliest timestamp for login
                loginTime = Application.Min(loginTime, srcSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value)
            Else
                loginTime = srcSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
            End If
            'prevAction = srcSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value
        ElseIf srcSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Release" Or srcSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Logout" Then
            ' Calculate total time based on login/logout pairs
            logoutTime = srcSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
            totalTime = logoutTime - loginTime
    
        'adjust the range as needed
        destlastRow = destWs.Cells(destWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
        ' Populate the array with values
        dataArr(1, 1) = srcSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value
        dataArr(1, 2) = srcSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value
        dataArr(1, 3) = srcSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value
        dataArr(1, 4) = totalTime
    
        ' Output the entire array to the destination range
        destWs.Cells(destlastRow, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value = dataArr
    
        End If
    Next i
    
    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    fileName = Dir     ' Get the next file
    
Loop
MsgBox "Data Extracted"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Here are the conditions to extract data:
1.destination sheet must contain headers Column A = DATE, column B = LoginID, column C = Name, column D = TotalTime(per user), column E = TOTAL_TIME(per month)
2.in source files if Column D contains login = "Get" or "Login" OR logout = "Release" or "Logout" then copy that row from column A to Column C. AND subtract logout-login value stored in column A to find out the total time spent based on login and logout pairs.
3.If column D contains two login = "Get" or "Login" value consecutively then copy that row from column A to Column C. AND keep track of the earliest login timestamp which comes first and do not miss login/logout pairs. use the earliest login timestamp value stored in column A for login value.
4.the calculated value from condition 1 and 2 must store it in column D = TotalTime(per user) in new destination excel file.
5.If column B = LoginID has more than one ID values of same users then look for column A values. If column A also has same "month and year" value for same users then do addition of the TotalTime(per user)value store in column D of destination file for that user. Store that addition values into column E = TOTAL_TIME(per month)

I'd suggest using Power Query to import the data into a data model and Power Pivot to perform reporting on the data.

"code is not working properly" - in what way exactly?

@TimWilliams Thank you so much for you time and help. I tried the provided code but it only extract the headers.

@TimWilliams i am trying to figure out why it only output headers.  i would greatly appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Did it open any files?  It worked for me with the files you provided

@TimWilliams i only changed the folder path and run the code. and in output sheet shows headers only.

@TimWilliams no,it does not open any files.

Then you may need to adjust the folder path?

@TimWilliams I changed the folder location but it still doesn’t work.

Have you tried stepping through the code using F8 ?

Yes I did. It shows sourceFile ”” , sourceWorkbook “ Nothing”

Code does not go through loop : Do While sourceFile<>””  it jump it exit the loop

@TimWilliams I figured it out. I added all the source files in same workbook and used Array and it work out perfectly. Thanks you so much. It really helped me out. I got to learn a lot of new things.Really appreciate your time and help.

Thank you everyone who voted to re-open this question. I really appreciate it.

Good to hear it's working out.

Here's one approach:
Add a new class module clsUsage with this code:
Option Explicit
'a simple class for collecting user login info
Public Yrmon As String
Public LoginId As String
Public Name As String
Public LoginDate As Date
Public TotalTime As Double

In a regular module:
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDataFromMultipleFiles()

    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet, destWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, destRow As Long
    Dim loginTimestamp As Date, logoutTimestamp As Date, k As String
    Dim TotalTime As Double, totalPerUser As Double, totalPerMonth As Double
    Dim LoginId As String, currentMonth As String, UserName As String, data
    Dim dict As Object, obj As clsUsage, sourceFile As String, v
    
    
    folderPath = "C:\Temp\Files\"  'files are here
 
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")   'for collecting results
    dict.comparemode = 1                              'case-insensitive
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    sourceFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While sourceFile <> ""
        
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & sourceFile)
        Set srcSheet = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        
        lastRow = srcSheet.Cells(srcSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        data = srcSheet.Range("A2:D" & lastRow).Value 'grab source data in an array
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1) 'loop over data array
            'key yr+month + userId + logonid
            k = Format(data(i, 1), "yyyy-mm") & "~" & data(i, 2) & "~" & data(i, 3)
            
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then    'new combo?
                dict.Add k, New clsUsage  'add new usage object
                Set obj = dict(k)
                With obj                  'set properties
                    .LoginId = data(i, 2)
                    .Name = data(i, 3)
                    .Yrmon = Format(data(i, 1), "yyyy-mm")
                End With
            Else
                Set obj = dict(k)         'seen before - just get existing record
            End If
            
            Select Case data(i, 4)  'login/out?
                Case "Get", "Login" 'user logging in - record time if not already there (in case of second login)
                    If obj.LoginDate = 0 Then obj.LoginDate = data(i, 1)
                
                Case "Logout", "Release"
                    If obj.LoginDate > 0 Then
                        obj.TotalTime = obj.TotalTime + (data(i, 1) - obj.LoginDate) 'increment by time spent logged in
                        obj.LoginDate = 0 'ready for next login
                    Else
                        'flag logout with no login?
                        Debug.Print "Logout with no login!"
                    End If
            End Select
        Next i
        sourceFile = Dir() 'next file
    Loop
    
    'output the collected data...
    Set destWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESULT")
    destWs.Cells.Clear
    destWs.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Date", "LoginID", "UserName", _
                        "TotalTime(per user)", "TOTAL_TIME(per month)")
    destRow = 2 'moved this out of the sourceFile loop
    
    For Each v In dict.keys  'loop over all dictionary keys and write each object's data to the sheet
        Set obj = dict(v)
        With destWs.Rows(destRow)
            .Cells(1).Value = obj.Yrmon
            .Cells(2).Value = obj.LoginId
            .Cells(3).Value = obj.Name
            .Cells(4).Value = DaysToHMS(obj.TotalTime)
        End With
        destRow = destRow + 1 'next output row
    Next v
    
    'TODO total up each yyyy-mm combo
    
    destWs.Activate
    
    MsgBox "Data Extracted"
End Sub


'Format period in seconds to DD:HH:MM:SS
Function DaysToHMS(ByVal p As Double) As String
    Dim arr, el, s As String, v As Long
    v = p * 86400 'days to secs
    arr = Array(3600, 60, 1)
    For Each el In arr
        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, ":", "") & Format(v \ el, "00")
        v = v Mod el
    Next el
    DaysToHMS = s
End Function

